# Need to add a "Search" filter in primeng and also Sr. No. in column 1

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am using Primgng with angular 4 and displaying json data in a table. How do I get  a "Search" filter as row 2. Row 1 is static headers and row 2 needs to have search filters ( for each column ). Also the json data does not return a serial number. How can I display serial number starting from 1,2,3..... so on considering the json data will be dynamic.
Here is my code...

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="persons" [immutable]="false" [rows]="10">
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" 
       [header]="col.header" [filter]="col.filter"></p-column>
   </p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Here is my code:  <p-dataTable [value]="persons" [immutable]="false" [rows]="10">
                    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [filter]="col.filter"></p-column>
                </p-dataTable>

Comment: You do not need to put your code in comment separately, you may edit your post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is already given in PrimeNg documentation. [PrimeNg Filter](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter) Please follow the steps as given.

For displaying S.No. Use below code:

```
 <p-table #tt [columns]="cols" [value]="data" [totalRecords]="totalRecords">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:70px;">S.No</th> // added header Explicitly.
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
     <th></th> // added empty header in row 2.
     <th *ngFor="let col of cols" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
             // Filters will go here
   </th>
   </tr>
   </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-i="rowIndex" let-suite>
   <tr">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td> //It will print Sr.No.
    <td *ngFor="let col of cols" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
    .
    .
    .
    </td>
    </tr>
   </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the filter to work but still struggling with the Sr. No. My "Sr.No" header is generated using 
                   <th *ngFor="let col of cols" style="text-align: center">
                        {{col.header}}
                    </th>

and  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="cols" let-i="rowIndex">
                <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                    <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                   gli </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template> for the body

Comment: I got your point. See my updated answer. You Just have to add <th> explicitly in Header(Row 1) and empty <th> in row 2.

Comment: I got it to work Thanks for your help. I think I was missing the explicit header

Comment: If it solve your issue. Please upvote and accept the answer :)